# ZooKeeper authentication error

Tags: kerberos, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to login to ZK using kerberos, and then perform some operations.
However, the following doesn't work:

```
2016-02-19 16:31:32,572 [myid:] - INFO  [Thread-1:Login@397] -Initiating re-login for <me/hostname@EXAMPLE.COM>

2016-02-19 16:31:32,588 [myid:] - INFO  [Thread-1:Login@301] - TGT valid starting at:        Fri Feb 19 16:31:32 PST 2016
2016-02-19 16:31:32,588 [myid:] - INFO  [Thread-1:Login@302] - TGT expires:                  Fri Feb 19 16:46:32 PST 2016
2016-02-19 16:31:32,588 [myid:] - INFO  [Thread-1:Login$1@181] - TGT refresh sleeping until: Fri Feb 19 16:43:50 PST 2016

[zk: hostname(CONNECTED) 11] 
[zk: hostname(CONNECTED) 11] getAcl /zk-test
'sasl,'me/hostname@EXAMPLE.COM@: cdrwa
[zk: hostname(CONNECTED) 12] ls /zk-test
Authentication is not valid : /zk-test
```

Even though I've already logged in using the principal `me/hostname@EXAMPLE.COM`, and the ACL for `/zk-test` is `sasl:me/hostname@EXAMPLE.COM:cdrwa`, I still cannot do simple stuff like `ls /zk-test`. Anyone know why? Thanks.

Comment: `Zookeeper` may not have been started with security enabled although it was previously enabled.

Comment: It's resolved: the ACL should not be in the format of `sasl:me/hostname@EXAMPLE.COM:cdrwa`, but of `sasl:me:cdrwa` (without the hostname & kerberos domain). This is recorded here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-2370. The behavior is not consistent with the documentation :(

Answer (score 3):

I wasted an hour of my life on this (thanks to poor documentation of zookeeper - everything is scattered), I want to make sure no one else does, thankfully someone who knows everything at our workplace helped me out ;)

Do this before you start zkCli -server blahblah:2181

```
    export JVMFLAGS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/tmp/jaas.conf -Dsun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1=dns,sun"
```

make sure you have jaas conf in tmp folder - I used something like this -

```
     Server {
      org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
      user_super="adminsecret"
      user_bob="bobsecret"
      user_dev="devpassword";
    };
    Client{
      org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
      username="blah"
      password="blahblah";
    };
```

it will work now.

Answer (score 1):

jaas.conf file is needed:

```
Client {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useKeyTab=true
  keyTab="/home/myUser/myUser.keytab"
  storeKey=true
  useTicketCache=false
  principal="myUser@MYREALM.COM";
};
```

Set environment variables for you current session:

`export JVMFLAGS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/myUser/jaas.conf"`

Finally connect to server:

`zookeeper-client -server myServerIp`

I've written a [blog pos](http://www.project2ist.com/2016/08/connecting-to-kerberos-secured.html)t about this as a note to self that should be a bit more complete.

Answer (score 0):

another way to start yarn  is to change yarn config:

```
yarn.resourcemanager.zk-state-store.parent-path /rmstore
yarn.resourcemanager.ha.automatic-failover.zk-base-path /yarn-leader-election
```

change the path to a new location ,so that   zk auth error can be avoid.

FIY：
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml